# Could not initialize SDL(No available video device), qemu-system, Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: x11, qemu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm learning how to write a basic OS kernel with [intermezzos.github.io](https://intermezzos.github.io)

I'm running in Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10 v1607.

I'm at the point where I want to run my `.iso` with `qemu-systems-x86_64 -cdrom os.iso`.

Previously I was able to run the command and QEMU would run a window, which was running into another problem, posted here: [QEMU, No bootable device, Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232676/qemu-no-bootable-device-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Now when running the command, I receive the following error: `Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting`

When I ran into this problem before I installed `Xming`, ran it, and then QEMU successfully ran. But now, when I try to run Xming it no longer solves the problem.

I even tried installing `xorg` and running `startx` on WSL but that starts another issue: `xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)`

I really don't know what I'm doing and I have so many questions.

I'm under the impression that for QEMU to successfully run, it needs to be able to find a video driver. Is that the purpose of X11?

Comment: WSL behaves like a headless box with a hardware terminal connected.  It can stream X protocol over TCP (looping back to localhost) which is why Xming worked.  StartX starts a local X server on a machine that _has_ a monitor (X servers are the things that multiplex and output window data to the screens, while X clients are the programs that create windows).

Comment: @HunterLester any luck? Running into exactly the same problem...

Comment: @BenGubler Hi Ben. Other than setting `export DISPLAY=:0`, I also had to `apt-get install grub-pc-bin`. See this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232676/qemu-no-bootable-device-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: @HunterLester thanks! I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get `qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom os.iso` to run the expected window after setting:  `export DISPLAY=:0`

Partially solves my problem because I'm still running into [QEMU, No bootable device, Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232676/qemu-no-bootable-device-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

I'm wondering if I'm setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable correctly.

Here's documentation on the `DISPLAY` variable, for anyone else that wants to learn: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/linux/display

Anyway, this portion is solved!